# PHP Form that updates a SQLite database

Tags: php, forms, sqlite, drop-down-menu

I need some help I am trying to create a PHP form using sqlite3 database. I am looking up values from from an existing sqlite3 database in the table2 where the column id = 340 and display those values as a dropdown selection. Then once the value is selected by the user  then the form is submitted by the users which updates the new values to the table1 with the values from the php form. I get it to display the names in the dropdown but when I click on the update button to submit the data it updates what the value is in the array.

For example lets say I have 3 fruits in the table and I select pear it updates the table with a "1" instead of the word "pear"

apple
pear
peach

### PHP entry page Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<div class = "controlbox">
<body style="font-size:12;font-family:verdana">
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<p> 
<h1>  </h1>
<br>
<br>
Slot1 : <select name="slot1">
<option>--Available Options--</option>
<?php
try
{
$db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt2 = $db->query ("SELECT * FROM table2 where ID = '340' ");
$rowarray = $stmt2->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$slot1 = 0;

foreach($rowarray as $row)
{
 echo "<option value = $slot1 >$row[FirstName] $row[LastName]</option>";
 $slot1++;
}
?>

</select><br>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP Code: Post.php

```
<?php

$slot1 = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['slot1']);

try
{
 $db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (!empty($slot1)) {
try
{   
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET Slot1place = :slot1 WHERE ID = '340'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':slot1', $slot1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

    echo "submitted successfully";


    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "<option name = $name >$row[FirstName] $row[LastName]</option>";
```

Everything else is the right syntax

Answer (score 1):

You dont use `sqlite_escape_string` if youre using a prepared statement like that. The values are going to be quoted witn they are bound to the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your html syntax (Is it missing   tags, and the  ).
Check it out at: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_option.asp